# ARM Outputs task adding "25" characters in the output variable

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I am deploying ARM templates via Azure DevOps by using “ARM Template Deployment” task. and using “ARM Outputs” tasks to read the output values of an ARM deployment and sets them as Azure Pipelines variables.

My ARM template containing following code in outputs section to read the logic app HTTP trigger URL.

```
    "httpEndpoint": {
         "type": "string",
         "value": "[listCallbackUrl(resourceId('Microsoft.Logic/workflows/triggers', parameters('LA-01Name'), 'manual'), '2016-06-01').value]"
}
```

It is reading the logic app HTTP trigger URL, but which contains few characters extra when compared with original http trigger URL in azure.

**Original URL**

> https://xx-xxx.eastus2.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/xxxxxxxxxxx/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=**%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2**Frun&sv=1.0&sig=xxxxxxxxxxx
>
> **ARM Output**
>
> https://xx-xxx.eastus2.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/xxxxxxx/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=**%252Ftriggers%252Fmanual%252**Frun&sv=1.0&sig=xxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Please see if my answer can help you. In your Original URL, there are some "*"s. Are they part of your URL? Or did you want to bold this piece, but it didn't show successfully?

Answer (score -1):

URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits. The browser encodes the input based on the character-set used in your page.

In your case, the character "%" is replaced by "%25". So it looks like the new URL has a few more characters. But in fact, it's the same URL as the original URL.

Comment: But while using that URL, I'm unable to call sub logic app due to forbidden error

Comment: It looks like this URL has been encoded twice. The orginal URL was supposed to be https://xx-xxx.eastus2.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/xxxxxxxxxxx/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=/triggers/manual/run&sv=1.0&sig=xxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Have you ever used this url as input information? Please try replacing it with `https://xx-xxx.eastus2.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/xxxxxxxxxxx/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=/triggers/manual/run&sv=1.0&sig=xxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Yes I'm using the URL inside the Main Logic App to call sub logic app.

Comment: Repeat to make sure I understand what you're saying, you didn't enter the original URL manually, it was completely captured by the task, right?

Comment: Yes @Jane MA-MSFT